# Не могу понять почему не отображаются балуны у меток Яндекс карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Почему то когда меняю иконку метки на свою то не отображается балун

```js
objectManager.add({
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "id": 1,
                        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.292826, 37.823287]},
                        "properties": {"balloonContent": "Детские сады"},
                        **"options": {"iconOffset": [-24, -64], "preset": "my#kinder"}**
                    },
                 
                ]
            });
```

Ниже представляю собственно созданную метку.

```
ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#kinder', {
            iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="circle_layout"><img src="/local/templates/sverdlova/img/map-3.svg"></div>'),
        });
```

Ссылка на страницу с картой
http://sverdlovadev.web-oblako.ru/location/

```js
<script>
        ymaps.ready(init);

        // map01
        function init() {

            var myMap = new ymaps.Map('ymap01', {
                    center: [51.290027, 37.834413],
                    zoom: 15,
                    controls: [],
                }, {
                    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search',
                    suppressMapOpenBlock: true
                }),
                objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
                    // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
                    clusterize: false,
                    // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
                    // gridSize: 32,
                    // clusterDisableClickZoom: true
                });

            // objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
            // objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');


            myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
            var listBoxItems = ['Детские сады', 'Школы', 'Рестораны', 'Кафе', 'Магазины', 'Бутики', 'Бассейны', 'Фитнес', 'Развлечения','Компания']
                    .map(function(title) {
                        return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                            data: {
                                content: title
                            },
                            state: {
                                selected: true
                            }
                        })
                    }),
                listBoxControl = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
                    data: {
                        content: 'Фильтр',
                        title: 'Фильтр'
                    },
                    items: listBoxItems,
                    state: {
                        expanded: true,
                        filters: listBoxItems.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
                            filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
                            return filters;
                        }, {})
                    },
                    options: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                });
            myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl);

            // Добавим отслеживание изменения признака, выбран ли пункт списка.
            listBoxControl.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
                var listBoxItem = e.get('target');
                var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, listBoxControl.state.get('filters'));
                filters[listBoxItem.data.get('content')] = listBoxItem.isSelected();
                listBoxControl.state.set('filters', filters);
            });

            var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(listBoxControl.state);
            filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {
                objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(filters));
            });

            function getFilterFunction(categories){
                return function(obj){
                    var content = obj.properties.balloonContent;
                    return categories[content]
                }
            };



            //myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#kinder', {
                iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="circle_layout"><img src="/local/templates/sverdlova/img/map-3.svg"></div>'),
            });
            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#school', {
                iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="circle_layout"><img src="/local/templates/sverdlova/img/map.svg"></div>'),
            });
            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#bank', {
                iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="circle_layout"><img src="/local/templates/sverdlova/img/cat4.svg"></div>'),
            });
            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#hospital', {
                iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="circle_layout"><img src="/local/templates/sverdlova/img/cat5.svg"></div>'),
            });
            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#shop', {
                iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="circle_layout"><img src="/local/templates/sverdlova/img/map-6.svg"></div>'),
            });
            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#bus', {
                iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="circle_layout"><img src="/local/templates/sverdlova/img/cat7.svg"></div>'),
            });
            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#pool', {
                iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="circle_layout"><img src="/local/templates/sverdlova/img/map-2.svg"></div>'),
            });
            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#fit', {
                iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="circle_layout"><img src="/local/templates/sverdlova/img/map-7.svg"></div>'),
            });
            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#apteka', {
                iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="circle_layout"><img src="/local/templates/sverdlova/img/cat10.svg"></div>'),
            });
            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#company', {
                iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<img src="/local/templates/sverdlova/img/logo_loc.svg">'),
            });

            objectManager.add({
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "id": 0,
                        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.291024, 37.827122]},
                        "properties": {"balloonContent": "Детские сады", "balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"},
                        // "options": {"iconOffset": [-24, -64], "preset": "my#kinder", }
                    },


                    // {
                    //     "type": "Feature",
                    //     "id": 0,
                    //     "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.291024, 37.827122]},
                    //     "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"},
                    //     "options": {"iconOffset": [-24, -64], "preset": "my#kinder"}
                    // },
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "id": 1,
                        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.292826, 37.823287]},
                        "properties": {"balloonContent": "Детские сады"},
                        // "options": {"iconOffset": [-24, -64], "preset": "my#kinder"}
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "id": 2,
                        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.291333, 37.811617]},
                        "properties": {"balloonContent": "Школы"},
                        "options": {"iconOffset": [-24, -64], "preset": "my#school"}
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "id": 12,
                        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.290883, 37.830311]},
                        "properties": {"balloonContent": "Магазины"},
                        "options": {"iconOffset": [-24, -64], "preset": "my#shop"}
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "id": 4,
                        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.284292, 37.827374]},
                        "properties": {"balloonContent": "Бассейны"},
                        "options": {"iconOffset": [-24, -64], "preset": "my#pool"}
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "id": 5,
                        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.292882, 37.821337]},
                        "properties": {"balloonContent": "Фитнес"},
                        "options": {"iconOffset": [-24, -64], "preset": "my#fit"}
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "id": 52,
                        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.290794, 37.831757]},
                        "properties": {"balloonContent": "Company"},
                        "options": {"iconOffset": [-24, -64], "preset": "my#company"}
                    },
                ]
            });

            // var objectState = objectManager.getObjectState(52);
            // if (objectState.isClustered) {
            //     // Сделаем так, чтобы указанный объект был "выбран" в балуне.
            //     objectManager.clusters.state.set('activeObject', objectManager.objects.getById(52));
            //     // Все сгенерированные кластеры имеют уникальные идентификаторы.
            //     // Этот идентификатор нужно передать в менеджер балуна, чтобы указать,
            //     // на каком кластере нужно показать балун.
            //     objectManager.clusters.balloon.open(objectState.cluster.id);
            // } else {
            //     objectManager.objects.balloon.open(52);
            // }

            var ym_checkbox_tags = {
                map01_filter01:'Детские сады',
                map01_filter02:'Школы',
                map01_filter03:'Рестораны',
                map01_filter04:'Кафе',
                map01_filter05:'Магазины',
                map01_filter06:'Бутики',
                map01_filter08:'Бассейны',
                map01_filter09:'Фитнес',
                map01_filter10:'Развлечения',
                map01_filter11:'Company',
            };
            $('.ym_filter_checkbox').on('change', function(e){
                var control_set = {};
                $.each(ym_checkbox_tags, function(inx, tag){
                    var checkbox = $('#'+inx);
                    if(checkbox.length > 0){
                        control_set[tag] = checkbox[0].checked;
                    }
                });
                listBoxControl.state.set('filters', control_set);
            });

            $(".all_category").click(function() {
                location.reload();
            });

        };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

У меток с пользовательским объектом по умолчанию нет активной области, поэтому click для вызова баллуна не срабатывает. Активную область для иконок можно задать через [iconShape](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/layouts.html), у Яндекса в песочнице есть [пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape/).